# jQuery: Add ui-close button to resizable/draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can I add a close button to a draggable/resizable div?

I understand that I am essentially describing a dialog, but I have to be able to take advantage of a few of the properties of resizable/draggable (such as containment) that are not a part of dialog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well if it's something that can be closed, doesn't that mean it can be opened?  If that's so, how is this different from a resizable, draggable dialog?

Comment: Yes it can be opened, a button on the page clones a resizable/draggable box.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that I essentially need a dialog that can be contained within a div.  The default functionality of a dialog does not have 'containment'.  You could extend the functionality of the dialog yes, but I figured it would be less time consuming to extend my resizable/draggable to just have a close button.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a solution:  create the dialog inside an iframe on your page.  the dialog will be contained within the iframe and the iframe is contained within a div...and wha-la, the dialog has "containment".

Answer (score 0):

Better solution, override the containment option in the ui core:

```
_makeDraggable: function() {
    var self = this,
        options = this.options,
        heightBeforeDrag;

    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        cancel: '.ui-dialog-content',
        handle: '.ui-dialog-titlebar',
        containment: 'document', //override this HARD CODED option
        start: function() {
            heightBeforeDrag = options.height;
            $(this).height($(this).height()).addClass("ui-dialog-dragging");
            (options.dragStart && options.dragStart.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
        },
        drag: function() {
            (options.drag && options.drag.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-dialog-dragging").height(heightBeforeDrag);
            (options.dragStop && options.dragStop.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
            $.ui.dialog.overlay.resize();
        }
    });
```

I can't believe the developers hard coded this instead of providing the containment option.  That's absolutely retarded.